# Finding balance of another user

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

I have a command for my bot which gets the balance (economy) of another user with mongoDB - currently to check your own balance you have to do !ponyo balance (your own tag) but it's tedious, so I made it so when no user is tagged that it will check the balance of the author. However, I am having some trouble doing so and it's erroring. Below is the error and the code.

````
client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  let member = message.mentions.members.first();
  if (member) {
    if (message.content.match('!ponyo balance') && profileSchema.findOne({ memberId: member.id, guildId: member.guild.id })) {
      console.log('trying to execute balance.createBalance() with the user id: ' + member.id)
      const profileBalance = await balance.createBalance(member);
      console.log(`profileBalance: ${profileBalance}`)
      await message.reply(`${message.mentions.members.first()} has ${profileBalance.coins} coins! :D`);
    }
  } else {
    if (message.content.match('!ponyo balance') && profileSchema.findOne({ memberId: member.id, guildId: member.guild.id })) {
      console.log('Trying to execute balance.createBalance() with the user id: ' + message.author.id)
      let member1 = message.author
      await balance.createBalance(member1);
      console.log(`profileBalance: ${profileBalance}`)
      await message.reply(`${message.author.tag()} has ${profileBalance.coins} coins!`)
  }}
})```
````

Answer (score 0):

You didn't actually include the error message you were getting, which was probably a mistake because you said you would post it, so I'm not sure what your error is. Regardless, your command wouldn't be working for the message author because after going into the condition where `member` doesn't exist, you then use a property of member, and as member is a falsy value, that would throw an error. Your conditional structure looks like this:

```js
if (member) {
    // code for getting the other member's balance
} else {
    // if this code is executing, it means member is undefined, so you can't use member
}
```

So in the else statement, this line **will not** work and will throw an error:

`if (message.content.match('!ponyo balance') && profileSchema.findOne({ memberId: member.id, guildId: member.guild.id })) {`

I see you already assigned another variable `member` with the message author, so try just deleting that line. If you do need this line then simply replace each "member" variable with `message.member`, e.g.

`if (message.content.match('!ponyo balance') && profileSchema.findOne({ memberId: message.member.id, guildId: message.guild.id })) {`

Comment: When I delete ```if (message.content.match('!ponyo balance') && profileSchema.findOne({ memberId: member.id, guildId: member.guild.id })) {``` **every** message is then replied with balance.

Comment: Then replace each of the `member` variable names with `message.member` or `message.author`, because `message.member` returns the member object of the user who sent the message.